# How to populate DataGrid from mySql

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio-2015, datagrid

What would be the simplest way to fill DataGrid with data from MySql Workbench database?
Database name is pop-sf40-database and it looks like this:
[image]

For now there is only one salon which I insert manualy.
(localhost root root)

Model: **Salon.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace POP_SF_40_2014.Model
{
    class Salon
    {
        private int id;
        private string name;
        private string adress;
        private string telephone;
        private string email;
        private string web_site;
        private string tin;
        private string uid;
        private string bank_account;
        private bool deleted;

    }
}
```

GUI **SalonWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="POP_SF_40_2014.GUI.SalonWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POP_SF_40_2014.GUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Салони" Height="500" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgSalons" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="572" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" LoadingRow="dgSalons_LoadingRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ИД" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Назив" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Адреса" Binding="{Binding Adress}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Телефон" Binding="{Binding Email}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Интернет адреса" Binding="{Binding WebSite}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ПИБ" Binding="{Binding Tin}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Матични Број" Binding="{Binding Uid}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Жиро рачун" Binding="{Binding BankAccount}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="285" Margin="15,119,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="345"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonId" Content="ИД" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,126,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" IsReadOnly="True"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonName" Content="Назив" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,155,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonAdress" Content="Адреса" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonAdress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,186,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonTelephone" Content="Телефон" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonTelephone" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonEmail" Content="Е-пошта" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonEmail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,248,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonSite" Content="Интернет адреса" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonSite" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,279,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonTin" Content="ПИБ" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,307,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonTin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonUid" Content="Матични број" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,338,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonUid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,341,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonBankAccount" Content="Жиро рачун" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,369,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonBankAccount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,369,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblSalonSearch" Content="Претражи" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,417,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSalonSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,420,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Додај" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Измени" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Избриши" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,173,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Сачувај" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,382,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSearch" Content="Претражи" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,421,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And it looks like this: 
[image]

Also, this is AppConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="POP_SF_40_2014.Properties.Settings.pop_sf40_databaseConnectionString1"
            connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;database=pop-sf40-database"
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Create and open a connection, and read a datatable using a datareader. I don't think you'll get much more information from anyone here until you run into an actual problem you can't solve and you explain what you've tried...

Answer (score 1):

It appears you will have to create a class for data access. Architecturally speaking, this will be placed on the Data Access Layer of your application (DAL).

You will have to use this object to retrieve information from your database and populate the Salon object. If you're using a DataGrid, then it probably means you'll be dealing with a list (ObservableCollection) of Salon objects.

[Here is a good thread on best practices when writing a DAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735566/what-is-the-best-approach-when-creating-data-access-objects)